# Marionette Embedded Events accessing ui hash

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I'm try to embed event handling inside of marionette but I got kind of stuck as when I embed events I loose the marionette view object which i require to update the width of a div to create an interactive slider.

```
 SliderBehavior = Marionette.Behavior.extend({
    ui: {
        slider: '.slider-pointer',
        foregroundScale: '.slider-default',
    },

    events: {
      'mousedown @ui.slider': 'onSliderDrag'
    },

    onSliderDrag: function(e) {
      console.log(this);

      var handlers = {
          mousemove : function(e){
              this.ui.foregroundScale.css({
                  width : utility.round((this.view.options.max - (e.pageX - this.view.options.offset)), this.view.options.min, this.view.options.max)+ 'px'
              });
          },
          mouseup : function(e){
              $(e.target).off(handlers);   
          }
      };

      this.$el.on(handlers);
    }
  });
```

So the problem is insde handlers >> mousemove >> the this object is representing the event how can I access my ui hash from inside this function.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick answer use $.proxy to inject your own scope

```
var handlers = {
      mousemove : $.proxy(function(e){
          this.ui.foregroundScale.css({
              width : utility.round((this.options.max - (e.pageX - this.options.offset)), this.options.min, this.options.max)+ 'px'
          });
      }, this),
      mouseup : $.proxy(function(e){
          $(e.target).off(handlers);   
      }, this)
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Try storing a reference to this in a variable outside of the handlers definition.

```
onSliderDrag: function(e) {
  console.log(this);

  var viewRef = this;
  var handlers = {
      mousemove : function(e){
          viewRef.ui.foregroundScale.css({
              width : utility.round((this.view.options.max - (e.pageX - this.view.options.offset)), this.view.options.min, this.view.options.max)+ 'px'
          });
      },
      mouseup : function(e){
          $(e.target).off(handlers);   
      }
  };

  this.$el.on(handlers);
}
```

Comment: I tried that yet it did not work it said viewRef is undefined

Comment: Not entirely sure as I can't test my code right now but I think the solution can ba achieved with $.proxy - which will set the this context for the handler will test it at home and get back to you